# ¿Como habilitar el acceso a una instancia EC2 con IAM y SSM?

Tags: aws

Tengo una aplicación que es ejecuta por linea de comandos que esta en una instancia EC2 y quiero que sea accesible vía SSM y IAM.

Pero no quiero que las personas puedan listar todas las instancias EC2 que existen, ¿como lo puedo hacer?

No soy un experto en aws pero si me dan una idea o artículos relacionados, me puedo manejar.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como se puede ver en la [documentación](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html) de AWS, únicamente es posible limitar la visibilidad de las instancias de EC2 por región (busca DescribeInstances en la página).

No obstante, lo que sí puedes hacer es evitar que puedan modificar de alguna forma las instancias que sí pueden ver de una región, para ello debes configurar adecuadamente los permisos de escritura de EC2, como:

- `StopInstances`
- `TerminateInstances`
- `RunInstances`
- ...

Otra cosa que puedes hacer es que cada instancia (o grupo de instancias) utilicen *keys* diferentes. De esta forma cada usuario únicamente podrá acceder a una serie de instancias. Quedando el resto fuera de su alcance al no disponer de las claves correspondientes.